# Java code showing error: "inner class can't be public"?

Tags: java, methods, inner-classes

```
class one {
    void methodOne(){
               public class Two {

                }
    }
}
```

Java code showing error: "inner class can't be public"?

Comment: okay? and what is your question about that? Why do you think to create an inner class like that inside a method?

Comment: I just want to know is it right to have a public class in a inner method like this?

Comment: not a public one, as Java is already telling you. You can't set any access modifiers within a method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Java, you can write a class within a method. These are called `method-local inner classes` and they will be of local types (pretty much like local variables), the scope of the inner class is restricted within the method, so it can't be `public` (more details [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/local-inner-class-java/) and [here](https://blog.engineering.publicissapient.fr/2012/11/08/back-to-basics-bien-maitriser-les-classes-internes-en-java/)).

Here is a complete example:

```java
public class MethodLocalInnerClassExample {
    private int x = 10;

    void printFromInner(final int a) {
        final int y = 10;

        class MethodLocalInnerClass {
            int w = 5;

            public void print(int z) {
                System.out.println("x + y - z + w + a = " + (x+y-z+w+a));
            }
        }

        MethodLocalInnerClass innerClass = new MethodLocalInnerClass(); // must come after the class' definition
        innerClass.print(5);
    }
}
```

Comment: By the way, method-local classes are rarely used.